# beautifulsoup select, передача формата текст

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть код

```
mathes = soup.find_all('div', class_='_3Sdru5UgY8N5jF729-bJHD')
for math in mathes:
    time = math.find('span', class_='_1rkQUAonwe5irynMAgt2u1').get_text(strip=True)
    goals = math.select('div._2cD5vzrU7r3ToIHzBKjD0W')
    link = math.find('a', class_='_1nO2YxHrIZ_7_iPU4qsbyU').get('href')
    print(time, goals , URL + f'{link}')
```

который выводит строки по типу `2-й тайм 60' [<div class="_2cD5vzrU7r3ToIHzBKjD0W">0</div>, <div class="_2cD5vzrU7r3ToIHzBKjD0W">0</div>]`
Смысл в том, чтобы переменная goals, выводилась в качестве текста. Например: `2-й тайм 60' 0 0`
Как добавить пробелы это понятно, а как передать переменной goals формат текста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собрать текст из списка в `goals`, а после все это вывести в форматированной строке:

```
goals_text = ' '.join(x.text for x in goals)
print(f'{time} {goals_text} {URL}{link}')
```